# vb call generic method

Tags: vb.net, generics

My question is, when calling a generic method in vb I am used to having to state what type i am passing. **Example 3**. I am running VS 2012 and now  I dont have to do this. **Example 2**. My question is when did this change, and how is this working(is the compiler reflecting the type to put in and letting me be lazy)?

```
Public function Foo(of T)(bar as T) As Boolean
return true
end function
```

**Example 2**

```
public sub TestFoo()
dim test as int = 0
Foo(test)
end sub
```

**Example 3**

```
public sub TestFoo()
dim test as int = 0
Foo(of int)(test)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler simply infers what type to use. This feature was available when generics were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 and 3 still exist in VS2012, they are  simply 2 different implementations.  One is using a Generic declaration the other is not.

Here is a good example:  [Explain Generics in layman style in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713438/explain-generics-in-layman-style-in-c)

Comment: Thank you, but I know they both exist in vs 2012. My question is when was this ability introduced and how does it work