# C# Generics - Can someone explain this signature

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I'm working with a C# opensource project called Merchello. I'm trying to customise it it a little bit but I don't think I fully understand some of the code.

There is an existing MVC controller that I may need to change but I don't fully understand how its put together -

I admit I am not to familiar with generics in C# - can someone give me an explanation of what this signature means in particular I would like to understand what TBillingAddress means. If you could also point me to any links that would help me understand this more.

```
public abstract class CheckoutAddressControllerBase<TBillingAddress, TShippingAddress> : CheckoutControllerBase
    where TBillingAddress : class, ICheckoutAddressModel, new()
    where TShippingAddress : class, ICheckoutAddressModel, new()
{
```

Comment: Have you tried to google this information? Here is an article from msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713438/explain-generics-in-layman-style-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560890/what-are-generics-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `TBillingAddress`:

- `class` - Means the type must be a reference type
- `ICheckoutAddressModel` - Means the type must implement this interface
- `new()` - Means the type must have a paramterless constructor

These all constrain what types can be used for `TBillingAddress` and constrain what you can do with the type in any method using it.

And `TShippingAddress` has the same constraints.

Also see:

- [where (generic type constraint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)