# The best way to convert List<Object> to ObservableCollection<Object>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have got `List<Object>` where the **Object** has a lot of childs `List<Object>` around 4-6 levels.

Now I have to bind it to WPF TreeView... :(

Which **the best way** to convert it into `ObservableCollection<Object>` is?

Comment: Why not just make them `ObservableCollection<object>` in the first place? When working with WPF, its important to get the data layer right, and if you're ever displaying a list that can change in the UI, you should always use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`

Comment: @Rachel Correct. The first place is RIA Services. I don't know if it is possible to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One part of the answer is to use Reactive Extensions (Rx). You can get it from NuGet and it's developed by Microsoft. With the help of it you can simply say: `myListCollection.ToObservable();`

If your child collections always are in a node with the same name you could use a `while(item.Collection != null || item.Collection.Count == 0)` and put the `ToObservable()` within the loop

Comment: This is such a overkill

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you mean `ObservableCollection<T>`, if you wanted the `List` directly to the `ObservableCollection` as-is, just use the constructor:

```
var oc = new ObservableCollection<Object>(yourListOfObject);
```

Now, if you're wanting to unwind each of those, you would need to do some work to collapse them into a single `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: If I created a public class called `Computer` and have a public string `Name` getter-setter inside there for my OC, and then I have a `List<string> lstComputers`, it tells me I `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.MainWindow.Computer>'`.

Comment: Actually I found out how to do it.  You can't have mismatched types.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about ObservableCollection.  To answer simply, you can use the ctor:

```
List<Object> myList = GetList();
new ObservableCollection<Object>(myList);
```

However, I think there is some work left to be done in terms of organizing your information hierarchically.

Comment: List<Object> is not a common usage of generics.  Start with a review of generics here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155260/what-is-the-syntax-within-c-sharp

Comment: In addition, here is a good blog post I just googled that details binding hierarchical data to a WPF TreeView: http://www.mattlong.com.au/?p=37

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a node class defined like so:

```
public class Node
{
    public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You can use recursion to convert `List<Node>` collections, at any level of depth:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Node> ToObservableRecursive(ICollection<Node> nodes)
{
    foreach (Node node in nodes)
        if (node.Children != null)
            node.Children = ToObservableRecursive(node.Children);

    return new ObservableCollection<Node>(nodes);
}
```

Comment: If I created a public class called `Computer` and have a public string `Name` getter-setter inside there for my OC, and then I have a `List<string> lstComputers`, it tells me I `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.MainWindow.Comput‌​er>'`

Comment: Actually I found out how to do it.  You can't have mismatched types.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)? If you want the child level `Lists` to be observable also then you will need to traverse the tree and change items as necessary or add each item separately to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do any of the solutions listed here until your types are the same!  If your list or ICollection or IEnumerable is of type `string`, for example, but your `ObservableCollection` needs to be of type `Nodes` or `Computers` or something else, you have to get the List into that type, first!  I wasted so much time on these other bogus, simplified "solutions" that are NOT solutions because they do not explain this or take this factor into account.

Say this is your `ObservableCollection`:

```
public class Computer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty standard, right?  You'd probably end up replacing `Computer` with any number of things in any number of projects.

If you then get a list of computer names in a `List<string>` called `lstComputers`, you CANNOT just convert that using:

```
var oc = new ObservableCollection<Computer>(lstComputers);
```

It will say your types are mismatched and cannot be converted from one to the other because you are trying to shove a `List<string>` into an `ObservableCollection<Computer>`.  Square peg in a round hole.

Instead, in your function for getting the computer names, you have to add them all "special-like":

```
public static List<Computer> NetworkComputers()
{
    List<Computer> lstComputers = new List<Computer>();
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
    foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
        {
            if (computer.Name != "Schema" && computer.SchemaClassName == "Computer")
            {
                lstComputers.Add(new Computer() { Name = computer.Name });
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Only because we used that line `lstComputers.Add(new Computer() { Name = computer.Name });` and are returning the `List<Computer>` and not `List<string>` can we now put it into our `ObservableCollection<Computer>`.

If you missed the boat and can't do it like this from the start, this thread talks about other ways you might be able to do your conversion:
[convert a list of objects from one type to another using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression)

So once you have it in a `List<Computer>`, only then you can do:

```
List<Computer> lstComputers = NetworkComputers();
var oc = new ObservableCollection<Computer>(lstComputers);
```