# Convert a List<T> into an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a `List<T>` which is being populated from JSON. I need to convert it into an `ObservableCollection<T>` to bind it to my `GridView`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069445/the-best-way-to-convert-listobject-to-observablecollectionobject/41731406#41731406

Comment: It is duplicate but its a bit too late since this question amounted way more attention. and you linking for your own answer seems rather low. IMO your answer expands unnecessarily out of the focus of the question. if the OP has `List<T>` no matter how many levels it has, it can do `ObservableCollection<T> xxx = new(listT);`

Answer (score 315, accepted):

ObservableCollection < T > has a constructor [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx)
which takes IEnumerable < T >

Example for a List of `int`:

```
ObservableCollection<int> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>(myList);
```

One more example for a List of `ObjectA`:

```
ObservableCollection<ObjectA> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<ObjectA>(myList as List<ObjectA>);
```

Comment: I prefer this over creating an extension method. Helps keep dependency count down.

Comment: How to achieve vice versa ?

Comment: @ArunPrasad var myList = myCollection.toList();

Answer (score 20):

ObervableCollection have constructor in which you can pass your list.
Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms653202.aspx):

```
 public ObservableCollection(
      List<T> list
 )
```

Answer (score 8):

The Observable Collection constructor will take an IList or an IEnumerable.

If you find that you are going to do this a lot you can make a simple extension method:

```
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(enumerable);
    }
```