# How can I make a linq call goes into my ObservableCollection variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, observable

I'm having an issue with my ObservableCollection. As you can see when I try to fill up the user collection it says that it cannot be converted.

If I use a list I can make it work but then the grid won't update the data while I make edits that's why I need a ObservableCollection.

I have tried to Google it myself but I could not find a solution sadly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Code]

Comment: This is _not_ a good use-case for an `ObservableCollection<T>`. You should just return them in a `List<T>`. Whereas `ObservableCollection<T>` types should only be used in long-life'd in-memory objects with observable state (i.e. a view-model). If your data isn't mutable, you don't need an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Ok and if i were to need a mutable list? how do i solve this then?

Comment: `List<T>` is mutable too. Just use that.

Comment: You're declaring `users` as an `ObservableCollection<T>`, then you try to replace it immediately after with an `IEnumerable<T>`. Use the ObservableCollection's constructor that accepts that source instead - If this is actually WinForms, not WPF, use a `BindingList<T>` (you need to cast the source collection to List to build it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432450/convert-a-listt-into-an-observablecollectiont