# How to cast a List<T> to an ObservableCollection<T> in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am in wpf, and have a generic list: List.
Now I wish to cast it to a generic observable collections: ObservableCollection.

I understand I can iterate over the list and add each individual item to the Observable collection.
However, it seems to me there has to be a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069445/the-best-way-to-convert-listobject-to-observablecollectionobject

Comment: Is that the built-in way? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202.aspx

Comment: There is no way to cast to an incompatible type, and even if it was there, your program will crash when you try to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to convert List<Object> to ObservableCollection<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069445/the-best-way-to-convert-listobject-to-observablecollectionobject)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you JUST want to create an `ObservableCollection` from a `List`, then all you need to do is

```
ObservableCollection<MyType> obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(myList);
```

Comment: Problem with this is it will try to shallow clone myList. For not doing it, do a foreach on myList and add it to obsCollection, this way references will be same.

Answer (score 2):

```
var _oc = new ObservableCollection<ObjectType>(_listObjects);
```

Answer (score 2):

ObservableCollection has Conttructor for `IEnumerable<T>` [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx)

```
ObservableCollection<yourType> observable = 
        new ObservableCollection<yourType>(yourListObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using extension method

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    var c = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (var e in coll) c.Add(e);
    return c;
}
```

or you can use this [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202.aspx) The elements are copied onto the ObservableCollection in the same order they are read by the enumerator of the list.

```
ObservableCollection<YourObject> collection = new ObservableCollection<YourObject>(yourList);
```