# WPF datagrid filter data binding List<T1> within a List<T> C#

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` binding to a `List<T>`.  Below is my class.  The `List<FSCLevel>` is binding to the `RowDetails` in my main `DataGrid`.  I have added a filter control for users to filter through `CUSTOMER_CODE`.

```
public class CUSTCARDLevel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members        
    private string _cUSTOMER_CODE;            
    private List<FSCLevel> _fSClist;        
    #endregion

    #region Properties       
    public string CUSTOMER_CODE { get { return _cUSTOMER_CODE; } set { _cUSTOMER_CODE = value; OnPropertyChanged("CUSTOMER_CODE"); } }      
    public List<FSCLevel> FSCLIST   { get { return _fSClist; } set {_fSClist = value;    OnPropertyChanged("FSCLIST"); } }
    #endregion

    // INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
   {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

I now need to apply some filters on the list, e.g. on `DataGrid` it only shows `CUSTOMER_CODE` is "CUST1".

So here is the question, do I have to use an `ObservableCollection` for the filter purpose?  Is there a way that I can just use the class with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?  If so, what is the best way to handle the `List<T1>` within a `List<T>`?  Say I cast my list into `ObservableCollection<T>` using:

```
ObservableCollection<CUSTCARDLevel> myObserveList = new ObservableCollection<CUSTCARDLevel>(myList);
```

What is going to happen to the `List<FSCLevel>` inside? or how do I cast `List<FSCLevel>` inside CUSTCARDLevel into ObservableCollection?  Or I need to do something to fix my class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering an ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782585/filtering-an-observablecollection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to put this as a comment but it went off the character limit. I'll get right to it.

Well it's all about the need of the hour.

> I would strongly recommend against the frequent casting using `new ObservableCollection<object>(myList)` since it'll each time return a new instance that'll take up `memory`.

Now let's assume you have a `List<T>` and any changes in the items of the `List<T>` you want to reflect on the UI then you should only use an `ObservableCollection` for the `List<T>` and not for any `List` that are a part of `Class T`.

On the contrary, if you have a UI that needs to be updated each time the `collection` in the `class T` is modified, I would recommend that you make it an `ObservableCollection`.

Generally in the most common ways, Developers use `ExtensionMethods` to convert a `List<T>` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18095971/3766231)

Also, they use `XAML Converters` and bind the element directly to the list.

> My final recommendation: Use an observable collection based on your needs as explained above but most importantly, don't operate on `Lists` unless it's actually necessary. Fetch the `data` from your service into a `List` convert it once into an `ObservableCollection` and then use `System.LINQ` to filter the data from it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Say if I make an ObservableCollection during my data preparation, what would happen to my 'List<FSCLevel>' inside my class?  Because I cannot do add ObservableCollection<FSCLevel> into my item (I can only put List<FSCLevel> during my data preparation.....Thank you

Comment: Yeah so the `List<FSCLevel>` would remain a list. Only your main list which holds your data would be an `ObservableCollection` that means any change in the values in `List<FSCLevel>` will not reflect automatically on the UI. If you do want to bind your controls to an observableCollection you can use data binding and `IValueConverter` to convert any binded list to an observableCollection