# Issues with a list containing multiple data types

Tags: c#, generics, icomparable

For a university task, I've been asked to write a program containing a class that finds the largest and smallest values of some data type. We must also satisfy the following requirements:

- Exploits generics with a single deferred type with an IComparable<> constraint;
- A List<> should be created (private) to contain objects of the deferred type;
- A method Add() should be provided to allow the objects to be added to the List<>;
- A method Minimum() should return the minimum value stored in the List<>;
- A method Maximum() should return the maximum value stored in the List<>;
- The Main() method must demonstrate your generic class being used

The following is my miserable attempt at this task.

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace task_eleven_point_three
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Generics<Type> Test = new Generics<Type>();

            Test.Add(3.1232M);
            Test.Add(1534);
            Test.Add(-74);
            Test.Add(432F);

            Console.WriteLine(Test.Maximum());
            Console.WriteLine(Test.Minimum());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the other class, which I've called Generics.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace task_eleven_point_three
{
    class Generics<T>
    {
        private List<T> _List = new List<T>();

        public TYPE Maximum<TYPE>()
            where TYPE : IComparable<TYPE>
        {
            TYPE Result = _List[0];

            for (int i = 1; i > _List.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (_List[i].CompareTo(Result) == 1)
                    Result = _List[i];
            }

            return Result;
        }

        public TYPE Minimum<TYPE>()
            where TYPE : IComparable<TYPE>
        {
            TYPE Result = _List[0];

            for (int i = 1; i > _List.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (_List[i].CompareTo(Result) == -1)
                    Result = _List[i];
            }

            return Result;
        }

        public void Add(T value)
        {
            _List.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

These are some of the errors I currently have:

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'TYPE'
- 'T' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- The type arguments for method 'task_eleven_point_three.Generics.Maximum()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I don't usually struggle with programming tasks, but generics really confuse me. If someone could fix my code, and tell me what I've done wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe irellevant but..should it be in loop  i < _List.Count - 1 ???

Answer (score 0):

At some Points you are using T and at others you are TYPE

The T to TYPE as you stated in class declaration

```
public void Add(T value)
{
    _List.Add(value);
}
```

Change above to This

```
public void Add(TYPE value)
{
    _List.Add(value);
}
```

and similar for other places

Answer (score 0):

You have two different generic parameters, `TYPE` and `T` are completely separate arguments, one of them is belongs to your class other one's are belongs to your methods.You need to use only one type argument not two.

And also you need to add `IComparable<T>` to `T`, you are trying to call `CompareTo` method on `T` but the constraint doesn't exist on `T`, you applied it to `TYPE` so you are getting the following error:

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo'

Change your code like this:

```
class Generics<TYPE> where TYPE : IComparable<TYPE>
{ 
    private List<TYPE> _List = new List<TYPE>();
```

And also remove ALL THE TYPES that you specify after the method name:

For example change this:

```
public TYPE Minimum<TYPE>()
```

To:

```
public TYPE Minimum()
```

And remove all the constraints on the methods.

Also, Generics are strongly-typed. Which means, if you create a `Generics<int>` you can't add it to a *float* or *double* without conversion. You have to find a common type between all your types, which is `object` in this case not `Type`.Or use *double* or *decimal*

Comment: I've changed all the T's to TYPE, and I'm getting this error multiple times:

Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TYPE' to 'TYPE @Selman22

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Container<int> container = new Container<int>();
        container.AddItem(4);
        container.AddItem(11);
        container.AddItem(6);

        Console.WriteLine(container.GetMaximum());

        Container<Person> container2 = new Container<Person>();
        container2.AddItem(new Person() { Age = 36 });
        container2.AddItem(new Person() { Age = 47 });
        container2.AddItem(new Person() { Age = 48 });

        Console.WriteLine(container2.GetMaximum().Age);
    }
}

public class Container<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private  readonly List<T> _items = new List<T>();

    public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public T GetMaximum()
    {
        return _items.Max();
    }
}

public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
    }
}
```

Check out this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generics can be confusing, so don't feel bad.

The first bullet point in your question mentions a *type constraint* which you haven't addressed yet, but it's important in this case. It limits the generic types you can use, so that The maximum and minimum functions make sense.

Your class structure should look like this:

```
class GenericList<T> where T : IComparable<T> // <-- this is the type constraint: only allow types that implement IComparable<T>
{
    private List<T> _list = new List<T>();
    public void Add(T element)
    {
        // code for Add
    }

    public T Maximum()
    {
         // code for Maximum
    }

    public T Minimum()
    {
        // code for minimum
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done everything you said, and now I don't have any errors in my generics class. However, the compiler still doesn't like my Main method at all. Adding to the list gives the error "Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'task_eleven_point_three.Generics<T>.Add(T)' has some invalid arguments", and it can't convert any data type to 'T'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following adaptations in your code, which will actually help you understand what you are doing:

- T is your generic type parameter. You don't need TYPE. Make sure you understand what generics is before proceeding. Check this thread: [What is the "< >" syntax within C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155260/what-is-the-syntax-within-c-sharp)
- Change the name of your `Generics<T>` to something like MyList or MyCollection or... That way it gives a beautiful sound when you read it and you can get a notion about what your class is about: MyList of T, MyList of int, etc.
- You need a constraint on `IComparable<T>`. Since this is a student assignment, I will not tell you how to do it, but I will explain what it means. Putting a constraint on generic type parameter `T` means that your T must implement/extend the interface/class specified in the constraint. So if you would have a constraint in your class saying `class MyClass<T> where T : IEnumerable<char>` (which is read *MyClass of T, where T implements IEnumerable of char*) that means you would NOT be able to create an instance of `MyList<int>`, because 'int' does not implement `IEnumerable<char>`. On the other hand, string implements `IEnumerable<char>` and following would be valid: `MyClass<string>`. Apart from that, inside your class, you would be able to  call any method defined in `IEnumerable<char>` on your T objects.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have renamed the class containing the list to MyList. TYPE has been completely removed as well. However, the compiler still doesn't like my Main method at all. Adding to the list gives the error "Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'task_eleven_point_three.Generics<T>.Add(T)' has some invalid arguments", and it can't convert any data type to 'T'. Any more suggestions?

Comment: What is your T when you create `MyList<T>`?

Comment: At the moment, it's this

`MyList<T> Test = new MyList<T>();`

I assume that's wrong though. I get this error twice: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You use T in your class to specify a generic argument. But when using your class you must specify the real type for T generic argument. Keep in mind the constraint, you have defined and give a thought to the example I provided in my answer: I would not be able to create an instance of `MyClass<T>`, but `MyClass<string>` or `MyClass<IEnumerable<char>>` would compile...